# Selenium web driver : Invalid selector: *:-webkit-full-screen-ancestor

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

So the following code used to work but now I ran it and it always gives me this exception. The code basically used to type in the search bar of youtube and click on the search button.

Code:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com");
driver.findElement(By.name("search_query")).sendKeys("Selenium WebDriver"+Keys.ENTER);
driver.findElement(By.id("search-btn")).click();
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
    // print the link text
    System.out.println(links.get(i).getAttribute("title"));
    // Print the href's
    System.out.println(links.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
}
```

The html of the bar is :

```
< input id="masthead-search-term" autocomplete="off" autofocus="" onkeydown="if (!this.value &amp;&amp; (event.keyCode == 40 || event.keyCode == 32 || event.keyCode == 34)) {this.onkeydown = null; this.blur();}" class="search-term masthead-search-renderer-input yt-uix-form-input-bidi" name="search_query" value="" type="text" tabindex="1" placeholder="" title="Search" dir="ltr" spellcheck="false" style="outline: none;">
```

The html for the search button is :

```
<button class="yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-size-default yt-uix-button-default search-btn-component search-button" type="submit" onclick="if (document.getElementById('masthead-search-term').value == '') return false; document.getElementById('masthead-search').submit(); return false;;return true;" id="search-btn" tabindex="2" dir="ltr"><span class="yt-uix-button-content">Search</span></button>
```

I tried it with javascript on and off but gave me the same exception. I tried to use xpath instead but gave me the same exception.

Exception trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.w3c.css.sac.CSSException: Invalid selector: *:-webkit-full-screen-ancestor
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSStyleSheet.validateSelectors(CSSStyleSheet.java:1195)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSStyleSheet.selectsPseudoClass(CSSStyleSheet.java:810)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSStyleSheet.selects(CSSStyleSheet.java:573)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSStyleSheet.selects(CSSStyleSheet.java:519)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSStyleSheet.selects(CSSStyleSheet.java:437)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSStyleSheet.selects(CSSStyleSheet.java:419)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSStyleSheet.modifyIfNecessary(CSSStyleSheet.java:251)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSStyleSheet.modifyIfNecessary(CSSStyleSheet.java:230)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Window.getComputedStyle(Window.java:1689)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomNode.isDisplayed(DomNode.java:714)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.isDisplayed(HtmlElement.java:1671)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement.isDisplayed(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:480)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement$1.call(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:276)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement$1.call(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.implicitlyWaitFor(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1353)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement.verifyCanInteractWithElement(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:273)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement.sendKeys(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:325)
at selenium.Counter2.main(Counter2.java:39)
```

Line 39 is line 3 in the example provided.
Im sorry if anything is missing or misleading. This is the first time to use stackoverflow. Ill be delighted for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot use Keys.ENTER. This is the corrected code-:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.findElement(By.name("search_query")).sendKeys("Selenium WebDriver");
driver.findElement(By.id("search-btn")).click();
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
 // print the link text
System.out.println(links.get(i).getAttribute("title"));
// Print the href's
System.out.println(links.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
}
```

Comment: This also gives the same exception. It seems to work for other websites but in Youtube it gives me this exception

Comment: I am surprised because code runs well on my system.

Comment: does it run on youtube? can you type in the search bar and click on the search button using the htmlunit driver? @Sandeep

Comment: Yes, it does exactly the same.

Comment: This is really wierd. I even tried updating to Selenium's latest version but the same exception occurs. I tried my code on another pc giving the same exception too. This piece of code was working a month ago and now its throwing this exception without me editing anything in it

Comment: Instead of HtmlUnit try using Firefox browser. show me the error trace after that.

Comment: 'WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();'

Comment: In my case i cant use firefox as the server im working on doesn't support browsers. Thats why i was choosing a seamless browser like htmlunitdriver, I tried it with firefox and it works. Thanks anyway for caring to answer :)